# Build and use Python without make install

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, installation

I just downloaded Python sources, unpacked them to `/usr/local/src/Python-3.5.1/`, run `./configure` and `make` there. Now, according to documentation, I should run `make install`.

But I don't want to install it somewhere in common system folders, create any links, change or add environment variables, doing anything outside this folder. In other words, I want it to be portable. How do I do it? Will `/usr/local/src/Python-3.5.1/python get-pip.py` install Pip to `/usr/local/src/Python-3.5.1/Lib/site-packages/`? Will `/usr/local/src/Python-3.5.1/python` work properly?

`make altinstall`, as I understand, still creates links what is not desired. Is it correct that it creates symbolic links as well but simply doesn't touch `/usr/bin/python` and `man`?

Probably, I should do `./configure prefix=some/private/path` and just `make` and `make install` but I still wonder if it's possible to use Python `make install`.

Comment: none of these commands will actually touch /usr/bin/python. As far as I have used them they create a new symlink /usr/bin/python35

Comment: @SiddharthGupta Thanks for insight! Indeed, `/usr/bin/python` won't probably be touched but I don't want `/usr/bin/python35` to be touched either.

Comment: If you're on Linux, you could leverage containers for a portable "sand box" of python. The most widely known tool set for this is [docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker), and it already has [officially supported Python containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)

Comment: @willnx Indeed, sandboxes and VMs may serve this purpose. But my question is still valid since I also have some interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to copy the binaries you built into a shared location for system-wide use, you should not `make install` at all. If the build was successful, it will have produced binaries you can run. You may need to set up an environment for making them use local run-time files instead of the system-wide ones, but this is a common enough requirement for developers that it will often be documented in a `README` or similar (though as always when dealing with development sources, be prepared that it might not be as meticulously kept up to date as end-user documentation in a released version).

Comment: I purposely left this general enough to cover the common case, not just Python.